# Search bug, or have I misunderstood how it works?

Tags: support, search

I just needed to search for an answer I wrote recently and used "[user:me router](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a4386%20router)", I then sorted by "Newest", but, the answer I wrote did not show up.

I wanted to find this question: [Ethernet in, Wifi out?](https://superuser.com/questions/324841/ethernet-in-wifi-out/324844#324844) and I was wondering if anyone knows why it didn't come up?

I have been using this feature for quite a whilst and never seen this issue before - is the answer too new/not indexed, or, have I misunderstood the way search works?

The Answer was "Aug 18 at 14:46"

[image: Search results]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[router](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/router) is one of SuperUser's more popular tags, and the search automatically converted your query to use a tag-based search. That particular question isn't tagged with the router tag, so it doesn't show up.

Remind search you know better than it does, and slap some quotation marks around the term. [Searching for `user:4386 "router"`](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a4386%20%22router%22) shows the answer you were looking for as the fourth result.

Comment: Thanks! I can understand that... but, out of curiosity, why doesn't the same answer come up with other terms such as `user:4386 "rj11"` with or without quotes? :/

Comment: @William - We only convert the very top tags (the top 40) to be tag searches, since those are the most common...converting *every* possible word wouldn't have a desirable effect :)

Comment: @Nick Craver - I understand that, but, what I don't understand is why rj11 in that question doesn't come up for a standard (non tag) search :/ e.g. searching for other single random words comes up with results where that word is highlighted, but, again in the example from my question, I typed rj11 and that answer did not come up with the word highlighted :/. I have probably typed rj11 at least 5-10 times, but, only one answer comes up upon searching.

Comment: @William - That's because you're looking for posts containing "rj11" *by a specific user*, which is narrows it to only one answer: http://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A4386+%22rj11%22

Comment: @Nick Craver - Sorry if I am not being clear - I know I am restricting it to one user! but, again, I have typed Rj11 a few times recently and that is the only question coming up.... I don't get that, for example again, why isn't this question http://superuser.com/questions/324841/ethernet-in-wifi-out/324844#324844 coming up in results?

Comment: @William - that'd be a different question...since `RJ11/Modem` is a single term there, it's a parsing question on the lucene side, e.g. searching for `user:4386 "RJ11/Modem"` would find it.  I'll look into it, but symbol delimiting (treating as spaces) on superuser isn't something we'd probably want to enable globally.

Comment: @Nick Craver - Ok fair enough - problem is with me then! No need to do anything special at all... That in combination with Tim Stone's answer, I am very happy.